Reorder a ggplot axis by a subset of data
Please see my figure in the image. Currently, the x-axis is ordered by the total number of nests per "bee of wasp group", so forested and open margin values (see legend) are added together. I want to instead order the x-axis by just the number of nests (y-value) in the open margin category. How would I do this? My current ggplot code is included. Dataset not necessary for this question.

ggplot(straw.gg.sum, aes(fill = Margin, y = sumNests, 
       x = reorder(str_to_title(straw.gg.sum$Builder), sumNests, decreasing = TRUE))) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
xlab("Bee or wasp group") + 
ylab("Total nests") + 
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, vjust=0.9, hjust=1, face="italic", size=8), 
     panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), 
     text = element_text(size  = 11)) + 
scale_fill_manual("Margin", values=c("forested"="yellowgreen", "open"="cyan3"))

See ggplot code (included in question)

I can't reproduce the problem or test a solution without some data.

There are a variety of prior questions on this forum related to reordering your data. Typically accomplished by making your sorted variable into an ordered factor. I like the forcats package for offering a variety of easy ways to assign that order. It'll be hard to be more specific without a reproducible example.

I ended up creating a dataframe with numbers assigned to all of the levels of the x-axis. When ordered in increasing order (1,2,3 ... 11) the axis has the order I wanted. Here is my complete code and the resulting graph.
#creating a df with the order I want
Builder <- c("megachile", "eumeninae", "osmia", "wasp", "hylaeus", "hoplitis", "trypoxylon", "isodontia", "chelostomoides", "dipogon", "passaloecus")
num.list <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11")
order.df <- data_frame(Builder, num.list)

#merging the new df with the data I want to plot
straw.gg.sum <- left_join(straw.gg.sum, order.df, by = "Builder" )
straw.gg.sum$num.list <- as.integer(straw.gg.sum$num.list)

#using ggplot
ggplot(straw.gg.sum, aes(fill = Margin, y = sumNests, x = reorder(str_to_title(straw.gg.sum$Builder), num.list, decreasing = FALSE))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "dodge") +xlab("Bee or wasp group") + ylab("Total nests") + theme(axis.text.x = eleme[enter image description here][1]nt_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.9, hjust=1, face = "italic", size = 8), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), text = element_text(size  = 11)) + scale_fill_manual("Margin", values = c("forested" = "yellowgreen", "open" = "cyan3"))



Something you could do if you can't provide the actual dataset that you're using is to provide a synthetic dataset that demonstrates the problem.
library(tidyverse)

straw.gg.sum <- tribble(
  ~Builder, ~Margin, ~sumNests,
  "Osmia", "forested", 30,
  "Osmia", "open", 40,
  "Megachile", "forested", 20,
  "Megachile", "open", 130,
  "Eumininae", "forested", 120,
  "Eumininae", "open", 80,
) 

levels = straw.gg.sum %>% 
  filter(Margin == "open") %>%
  arrange(.by = Margin, desc(sumNests)) %>% 
  purrr::pluck("Builder")

straw.gg.sum$Builder <- factor(straw.gg.sum$Builder, levels = levels)

ggplot(
  straw.gg.sum, 
  aes(
    fill = Margin, 
    y = sumNests, 
    x = Builder
    )
  ) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")

